# How to transform a project into an Android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I put my Android Eclipse project in SVN and checked it out again on another computer. However, Eclipse seems to be missing something, because it is not seeing it as an Android project.

What files or settings do I need to set to transform my tree into an Android project?

**Update** removing the project and reloading it from SVN did the trick. No idea what file was reloaded though, or how to "fix" a project.

Comment: Did you use File => New => Project, then Android => Open Android Project from Sources ?

Comment: No. I did Project -> New -> SVN -> Checkout Project from SVN (which by the way did work for another project, but I cannot find the differences ... )

Comment: If you're checking out the code on another machine, does the Eclipse have the ADT plugin installed?

Comment: If you could try to get files down locally using any SVN tool. Then try importing from Eclipse via Existing Android Project

Comment: @Vino I want to use the Eclipse SVN tools.

Comment: Yes of course you can use. This is to check whether the problems is with Eclipse SVN or with the code. Have you tried in any other machine?

Comment: In my development environment we just import all projects using File->Import->Existing Projects into workspace (and don't copy them) and this works perfectly with no issues. I have also checked out projects from GIT Hub/SVN of Google Code and never faced any issues. What is the error that you see in Eclipse "Problems" section?

Comment: @Swaroop I do not see any "Problems". I also cannot build. Eclipse sees (saw; it is fixed now) the project as a normal tree of files, not a Java project (or even Android).

Comment: The chances are that you 'checkedout' a wrong (one level up or down) directory which doesn't contain the required .classpath and .project files where eclipse looks for Android related entries like

`<classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>  
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>  
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>`

Can you try to manually import the project after check-out to another location? We do this all the time and it works perfectly.

Comment: @Swaroop see my update. It works now. I just removed the project and checked out again. I guess Eclipse does something on "Create New Project" that it cannot do afterwards.

Comment: What I think could've happened was when Eclipse couldn't find the required .classpath/.project files before it created dummy non-Java or non-Android project for you.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has problem to recognize project as android project if you checkout from svn.

You need to do somthing like this:

1) Open new android project

2)delete from **Your** android project -this three files: .classpath / .project / .project.properties

3) add from new android project that you create this files.

4)clean and build your project